# Relay filestream through multiple sites

Tags: c#, sharepoint, memory-management, stream

I am trying to pass large (500-1000MB) files from a SharePoint web through multiple sites. My problem is that the entire file ends up in memory, which is obviously bad. When requesting a 500MB file, I see memory allocation across the entire system rise by 1-1.5GB.

The setup is as following:

[image: Architecture]

A client requests a file from *Site A*. *Site A* then requests this file from *Site B*, which lastly requests this file from a SharePoint web. Relevant methods on Site A and B are implemented as handlers (.ASHX).

**ProcessRequest - Site A**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        using(var stream = client.OpenRead( ... url to Site B ...)
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                ... header setting emitted for clarity ...

                stream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ProcessRequest - Site B**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    using (var stream = Resolve<IDocumentService>().StreamDocumentFromSP( ... paramaters to get correct file ...))
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
    }
}
```

**StreamDocumentFromSP - Site B**

```
public Stream StreamDocument(... paramaters to get correct file ...)
{
    SPFile tempFile = null;

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
    {
        using (var site = new SPSite(url))
        {
            using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                tempFile = web.GetFile(itemGuid);
            }
        }
    });

    return tempFile.OpenBinaryStream();
}
```

**CopyTo**

```
public static void CopyTo(this Stream input, Stream output, int bufferSize)
{
    if (!input.CanRead) throw new InvalidOperationException("input must be open for reading");
    if (!output.CanWrite) throw new InvalidOperationException("output must be open for writing");

    var buf = new[] {new byte[bufferSize], new byte[bufferSize]};
    var bufl = new[] {0, 0};
    var bufno = 0;
    var read = input.BeginRead(buf[bufno], 0, buf[bufno].Length, null, null);
    IAsyncResult write = null;

    while (true)
    {
        // Wait for the read operation to complete
        read.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        bufl[bufno] = input.EndRead(read);

        // If zero bytes read, the copy is complete
        if (bufl[bufno] == 0)
            break;

        // Wait for the in-flight write operation, if one exists, to complete
        // The only time one won't exist is after the very first read operation completes
        if (write != null)
        {
            write.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            output.EndWrite(write);
        }

        // Start the new write operation
        write = output.BeginWrite(buf[bufno], 0, bufl[bufno], null, null);

        // Toggle the current, in-use buffer and start the read operation on the new buffer.
        bufno ^= 1; // Faster than: bufno = bufno == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        read = input.BeginRead(buf[bufno], 0, buf[bufno].Length, null, null);
    }

    // Wait for the final in-flight write operation, if one exists, to complete
    // The only time one won't exist is if the input stream is empty.
    if (write != null)
    {
        write.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        output.EndWrite(write);
    }

    output.Flush();
}
```

Ideally memory allocation should not rise by much more than the buffersize in my CopyTo method. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by flushing the output stream manually after each cycle, in my CopyTo-method. Then, in ProcessRequest for both sites A and B, I set:

`context.Response.BufferOutput = false`

And that did the trick. I was unaware that HTTPHandlers by default buffer the entire response stream.